# What does "parallel in-register" mean for a protein structure in a fibril?

Tags: biochemistry, terminology, proteins

I read a paper by Ross and Poirier [[1, p. S12](https://doi.org/10/dppb95)] which has the following lines (see section *Commonalities of amyloid structure*) that describe the structure of protein in a fibril:

> The most extensively characterized amyloid fibril is that formed from the β-amyloid (Aβ) peptide implicated in AD. Using SOLID-STATE NUCLEAR MAGNETIC RESONANCE SPECTROSCOPY, the in-register, parallel β-sheet organization of fibrils formed by Aβ<sub>10–35</sub>, a fragment of the full-length 42-residue Aβ peptide, was first described.

I couldn't understand what "*in-register, parallel β-sheet*" means.

#### References

1. Ross, C. A.; Poirier, M. A. Protein Aggregation and Neurodegenerative Disease. *Nat Med* **2004**, 10 (7), S10–S17. https://doi.org/10/dppb95.

Comment: Searching 'protein structure' gets 250 hits on chemistrySE, and 500 hits on biology SE.  Thus you might have luck on either site.  I'd give it a bit, and if you don't get a satisfactory answer here, ask it on biologySE (or perhaps ask that the question be moved there).

Comment: Have you looked for ref 43 in that paper, as this refers to the particular statement. Otherwise you could try emailing the authors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a clear explanation and figure showing this in the following reference:

[Anton Gorkovskiy, Kent R. Thurber, Robert Tycko, Reed B. Wickner, *PNAS* **2014**, *111* (43) E4615-E4622.](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/111/43/E4615.full.pdf)

A parallel beta sheet is one where the direction from N- to C-termini on adjacent strands run in a parallel direction (rather than antiparallel). In-register means that each residue in one molecule is aligned with the same residue in the neighboring molecule, producing lines of identical residues along the long axis of the filament.

Comment: Panel b of figure 1 shows the common position of a given amino acid in each aggregated peptide along the la-axis of the fiber; axes defined in panel a of the same figure.